# Faster "release" build from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am relatively new to Xcode.  We are testing an app that displays incoming data and it needs to be as fast as possible.  With other platforms I need to change from "debug" to "release" in order for optimizations to kick in and debug code to be removed, which can have a profound effect on speed.  What are the equivalent things I need to do in Xcode to build in fast/release mode?

(I am googling this and see lots of hits that seem to be in the general vicinity but I might be a little thrown off by the terminology, I might need it dumbed down a bit :))

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Edit the scheme to use release configuration.

Comment: Well shoot... I kept trying to select the type of build on the left of the edit scheme dialog, but it wasn't "Sticking."  I see now that debug/release is selectable for each of the "run/test/analyze/archive" types.  Thanks!

Comment: I add it as an answer if you would like to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the scheme to use release configuration.

Answer (score 7):

The first step is to set the Optimization Level for release as described above.  There are lots of options here.  From the clang LLVM compiler man page (man cc) -- (note that -Os is the default for Release):

```
   Code Generation Options
   -O0 -O1 -O2 -O3 -Ofast -Os -Oz -O -O4
       Specify which optimization level to use:

       -O0 Means "no optimization": this level compiles the fastest and
           generates the most debuggable code.

       -O1 Somewhere between -O0 and -O2.

       -O2 Moderate level of optimization which enables most
           optimizations.

       -O3 Like -O2, except that it enables optimizations that take longer
           to perform or that may generate larger code (in an attempt to
           make the program run faster).

       -Ofast
           Enables all the optimizations from -O3 along with other
           aggressive optimizations that may violate strict compliance
           with language standards.

       -Os Like -O2 with extra optimizations to reduce code size.

       -Oz Like -Os (and thus -O2), but reduces code size further.

       -O  Equivalent to -O2.

       -O4 and higher
           Currently equivalent to -O3
```

You will notice the 'Ofast' option -- very fast, somewhat risky.

A second step is to consider whether to enable "Unroll Loops".  I've read that this can in some code lead to a 15% speed increase (at the expense of debugging, but not an issue for Release builds).

Next, consider whether you want to Build and use an Optimization Profile.  See [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/xcode_profile_guided_optimization/pgo-tasks/pgo-tasks.html) for details, but the gist is that:

> Profile Guided Optimization (PGO) is a means to improve compiler
>   optimization of an app. PGO utilizes a specially instrumented build of
>   the app to generate profile information about the most commonly used
>   code paths and methods. The compiler then uses this profile
>   information to focus optimization efforts on the most frequently used
>   code, taking advantage of the extra information about how the program
>   typically behaves to do a better job of optimization.

You define the profile and whether you use it under Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 6.0 - Code Generation -> Use Optimization Profile.

Answer (score 3):

First have a look at this part in Xcode (screenshot of Xcode 5 but same on Xcode 6)[image: Xcode optimization]

You should also prefer PNG to Jpeg (as Jpeg requires more calculation - but are generally smaller in terms of size so better for network...)
Finally, Use multi-threading.
Those are (to mu humble opinion) the first steps to look at.